# I have a Dataframe with a lot of text content and I wish to save it as a table (in .PNG) with some formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pdf

I have a Dataframe with a long text content and I wish to save it as a table (in .PNG) with some formatting. Can you please suggest the packages and technique? I'm a newbie to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `dataframe_image`
https://pypi.org/project/dataframe-image/

```
pip install dataframe_image
```

Import the packages

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dataframe_image as dfi
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 6), columns=list('UVWXYZ'))
```

Add some gradient

```
df_styled = df.style.background_gradient()
```

```
dfi.export(df_styled,"dataframe.png")
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add a vote, but thank you it has sorted the issue. :)

Comment: glad to help. Please mark the answer as accepted